# unexpected behavior on casting

Tags: c++, casting, operators, operator-overloading

I have a doubt about how C++ casts types when it has to do math.

The code below as it is ( i.e. with only the cast to int without casting to double ) works and builds without problem. If I define `ENABLE_DOUBLE_CAST` doesn't build and complains about `operator*`. Do you know why?

The doubts I have are 2:

1. why without the operator cast to double, it is used the one to int in a multiplication between double. Is it because of the implicit cast?
2. why WITH the cast to double enable ( adding more clarity to the syntax ) that is not taken into consideration?

Thanks

AFG

```
class CA{
    int _m;
public:
    CA( int a, int b ){
     _m=a*b;
    }
    operator int (){
        std::cout<< "(CA int cast)" ;
        return _m;
    }
#ifdef ENABLE_DOUBLE_CAST
    operator double(){
        std::cout << "(CA double cat)";
        return 2.3 * _m;
    }
#endif
};

int main( int argc, const char** argv){
    CA obj_2( 10,20 );                  

    double total_1 = 100.0 * obj_2;   
    double total_2 = obj_2 * 100.0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've heard about user-defined conversion, but not user-defined `operator*`? You need to define the latter. In fact, you've to define two versions of `operator*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***why without the operator cast to double, it is used the one to int in a multiplication between double. Is it because of the implicit cast?***

Yes that is true.
It uses the `operator int ()` to convert `obj_2` to an int and then uses the inbuilt `operator*(double, int)`

***why WITH the cast to `double` enabled ( adding more clarity to the syntax ) that is not taken into consideration?***

When you provide both `operator double()` and `operator int ()` for your class, it creates an ambiguity, whether to convert `obj_2` to an `int` or `double` because there are two inbuilt operator overloads which it can use, namely:

```
operator*(double, int)
operator*(double, double)
```

***Suggestion:***
You should overload the `operator*` for your class if you want to avoid this problem of implicit conversions and ambiguity arising over it.

```
operator*(double,CA) and
operator*(CA,int)
```

Comment: Hi Als. Thanks for you clear explanation. I always though that the C++ built-in binary operators were limited to arguments WITH THE SAME TYPE so operator*(double,double) or operator*(int,int). Basically you are saying that C++ provides also the ones with different types?

Comment: @Abruzzo Forte e Gentile: Yes all aithematic operators for inbuilt types are provided implicitly in C++. You can overload them only when one of the operands is a custom class.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that with both casts you have ambiguous code, the compiler can't decide whether to use the int cast or the double cast, both are legal.

The rules on implicit casting are complicated and I'm not going to try and repeat them here (it would literally take pages and pages to cover everything). But if it generally agreed that to add implicit casts to your classes is a bad idea because of ambiguity issues like the one you have seen. If you want to use CA with operator* then it is better to define operator* for your class. E.g.

```
CA operator*(CA x, CA y)
{
  ...
}

CA operator*(CA x, int y)
{
  ...
}

CA operator*(CA x, double y)
{
  ...
}

CA operator*(int x, CA y)
{
  ...
}

CA operator*(double x, CA y)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi John. Reading other posts, your general rule about avoid it is fine. Side question if you don't mind! Is there any situation when these cast operator might bit of minimum help? If generally speaking they have to be avoided, why they are still around? Any use case on top of your mind?

Comment: I suppose the commest use case is a conversion to a boolean value, suppose with your `CA` class you wanted to use it as a boolean, like this `CA ca = ...; if (ca) ...`. That's actually quite difficult to do without introducing lots of ambiguity or surprising conversions. It can be done though, and it's called the _safe bool idiom_, Here's a good link for more reading http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html